# Plane not moving with armature/mesh

Tags: modeling, animation

I have this model where I'm using a plane with a texture as eyes. I want this plane to be connected to both, the body and the armature so that I can animate easily. However for the life of me I cant get the plane to connect and move with **anything**. I've tried joining, parenting, adding modifiers and nothings working. (I've attempted all those methods with both the armature and mesh) Any help is appreciated

Video to show what I mean:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rWG7Y17t6gMlYxCgzaGcl8dTl56I-l9V/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You've parented the eyes to the body but they won't follow the head if you move the bone head. Deparent and parent the eyes to the head bone, or join the eyes to the body mesh, then in Edit mode select the eyes vertices and assign them to the same group as the head. Also your mesh seems high-poly, which is not optimal for animation